# encoding in Java StAX parser

Tags: java, xml, encoding, stax

I'm using StAX to read XML file, but having problem with characters like žćčšđ.
The code is almost same as in the SAX, but i had not that kind of problem with that.

this is part of xml document

```
<?xml version = "1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>      
<Autor>
        <Id>1</Id>
        <Meno>Jano Žiška</Meno>
        <Email>dfdsfsfdsdf@gmail.com</Email>
        <tel_cislo typ="mobil">0944564685</tel_cislo>  
        <plat>500</plat>
      </Autor>
```

java

```
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            try {
              XMLInputFactory f = XMLInputFactory.newInstance();
              XMLStreamReader r = f.createXMLStreamReader(new FileReader(SUBOR));
            }
....
          if (r.getLocalName().equals(ELEMENT_MENO) == true) {
            String v = r.getElementText();
             System.out.println("meno:\t\t\t " + v);
          }
```

how can i specify encoding in java?
thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless you have a *really good reason*, you should always use *binary* streams with XML (InputStream/OutputStream), not character streams (Reader/Writer).  using character streams risks corrupting the xml (as the OP's original code shows).

```
XMLStreamReader r = f.createXMLStreamReader(new FileInputStream( SUBOR ));
```

Comment: Whar is it explained why this is the case?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using FileReader, do this:

```
XMLStreamReader r = f.createXMLStreamReader(
        new InputStreamReader(
                new FileInputStream( SUBOR ),
                Charset.forName( "UTF8" ) ) );
```

Comment: thanks, but i dont understand why is it different from SAX. I guess something in api..

Comment: Actually, you shouldn't be using a Reader at all, you should be using the InputStream directly.